# Determine whether a Postgres materialized view is currently being refreshed, within a trigger function

Tags: postgresql

I have a materialized view that I'd like to refresh concurrently when a source table is updated. Concurrent refreshing is used to avoid blocking reads for the duration of the refreshm

Currently, I accomplish that via a trigger function on update/insert to the source table. However, if there are a large number of inserts all at once, the numerous refreshes and index updates degrade my database performance.

Is there a way to set up a trigger function such that, if a particular materialized view is not currently being refreshed, I trigger a concurrent refresh - but, if a refresh is already ongoing, I don't attempt another one, and instead just no-op within the trigger?

Alternatively, is it possible to kill all currently-ongoing refreshes of a particular materialized view?

Comment: Refreshing a materialized view whenever the underlying data change is madness, particularly if there are many data modifications. Don't do that, run a regular `REFRESH` through a scheduler.

Comment: The only reason to refresh a materialized view after each DML to the underlying tables is if it **absolutely must be 100% current**. Normally an unlikely condition unless that is a legal/regulatory requirement. But even then you do not need the refresh run after each row.  Change your trigger to a *statement level trigger*; runs only once regardless of number of rows processed.  See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Yeah, it's not a great design but there's some legacy systems I need to work around. Statement level trigger is exactly what I needed - can't believe I missed that in the docs. Thanks!